# Deleting All Footers with Apache POI XWPF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a Word docx file.  The document contains multiple page footers.   How can I delete all of the footers from the document?  I'm able to create a new one with the HeaderFooterPolicy and I'm able to modify the runs of an existing one, but I'm not sure how to completely eliminate the existing ones.

Essentially what I'd like to do is remove all existing footers and create a new default that will apply to all pages.

Is that possible in the current poi?

Comment: For problem are you facing in modifying current `XWPFRun`s?

Comment: What version of POI are you using?